# Using long doubles on windows

Tags: c++, windows, mingw

I have an application where I absolutely must use `long double` data type due to catastrophic truncation error when doing math with double precision.  My testing procedures are going crazy because on windows long double with Visual Studio is just an alias to double, while on linux and OSX, long double is a real long double with nominally precision of 1e-19.

On mingw (windows port of GCC) is where I am confused.  Mingw claims that LDBL_EPSILON has a precision of 1e-19, but googleing suggests that the mingw uses the c runtime that is actually just the microsoft c runtime which doesn't support real long doubles.  Can anyone shed any light here?

**EDIT**:  The crux of the problem is this: on mingw, if I call the math function `log(long double x)`, is this just an alias to `log(double x)`?  In either case, how could I write my own script to test this behavior and/or test for it?

Comment: basic arithmetic is usually part of the language and not part of the `C runtime` which mostly refers to the implementation of the C standard library and the run-time facilities like signal handling, memory allocation, etc.

Comment: But aren't mathematical functions part of the c runtime? log(long double) for instance?  Pardon my ignorance if I am mistaken

Comment: a common newbie mistake is to subtract two roughly equal numbers. anyway, good idea to first look at the algorithm(s).

Comment: Yes I am far from a newbie, algorithms have been heavily optimized to avoid truncation, etc.

Comment: ergo -> I really do need long double

Comment: Depending on how many of the math operations you're using, you could implement your own long double functions in assembly. Don't forget to set the floating point control word to handle 80 bit numbers (I think Visual Studio sets it to 64 bit numbers).

Comment: long double is only guaranteed to be as long as a double.  So, while it isn't an 80-bit data type (at least on Windows 64-bit ABI), it does meet the requirements of C++11.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main(void)
{
    long double y = 2.0L;

    std::cout << sizeof(y) << std::endl;

    long double q = sqrt(y);

    std::cout << q << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

produced output 16 1.41421, so far so good

Ran it throw preprocessor (-E option) and found out that internal, but different from double sqrt() function were called

```
using ::sqrt;

inline constexpr float sqrt(float __x)
{ return __builtin_sqrtf(__x); }

inline constexpr long double sqrt(long double __x)
{ return __builtin_sqrtl(__x); }
```

Same for log(), sin(), you name it

Thus, I believe MinGW support long double format in arithmetics as well as in math.functions, and this support is built-in, not libquadmath based

Answer (score 2):

Just tried with MinGW (MinGW distro from nuwen, gcc/g++ 4.9.1, 64bit)

Following program

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
    double x = 1.0;
    long double y = 2.0L;

    std::cout << sizeof(x) << std::endl;
    std::cout << sizeof(y) << std::endl;
}
```

produced
8
16

I would guess, long double is supported and is different from standard double, thus
your computations might produce desired result

I've heard there are problems with printing long doubles on Windows due to using MS old runtime.
You might have to use casts or roll your own output routines

Comment: The printing of long doubles has been fixed in mingw, you just need to do %Lg instead of %g for general floating point output.  That is excellent news and greatly appreciated.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if on Windows GCC mapped "long double" to __float128 type from libquadmath. I suggest to check libquadmath docs, this library has all math functions and conversion to/from string.

Comment: Just checked above mentioned MinGW 4.9.1 distro, it does have libquadmath.a installed

Comment: quad math is SUPER slow, and since performance is also very important, I need long doubles, not quads

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, quad math is software emulated, while long doubles can be used in some SSE libraries

Comment: Ok, tried to call sqrt() for long double, and it worked. But tried to call sqrtq() (which is libquadmath code) and it didn't work. Ergo, long double in MinGW is NOT a libquadmath __float128